# Using mklink in Windows7

Tags: windows-7, symbolic-link

I have two usb flash drives `D:\` and `H:\`, inside they have some bin files

`001.bin,002.bin` on D

`003.bin 004.bin` on H

I want to create a symbolic link in such a way that when a program accesses `C:\bins` it will find inside all files `001.bin,002.bin,003.bin,004.bin` from the usb drives, and access them from the usb drives.

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to individually link each file?

Comment: @Bob I'm not planning to remove the drives in this case so I'm fine with that, and yes I would like to individually link each file. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was thinking of junction points. I've never tried symbolic links cross drive with removable media.

Comment: Ok, just tried it. Changing the drive letter does break the link, so beware of that.

Comment: @Bob: It should be possible to avoid this by creating symlinks using the volume GUID instead of drive letter, as in `\\?\Volume{1234-56-...}\001.bin`. (This is what mountpoints and junctions use by default.)

Comment: @grawity That seems to work perfectly. I'm rather annoyed I never thought of that ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is impossible to merge two directories using a single symlink, since a link can only have one target. This applies equally to junctions and symbolic links. (On Linux this could be achieved at VFS layer, by using virtual filesystems such as *overlayfs* or *unionfs*; some other Unix-like systems also have similar concepts of "union mounts". No such thing on Windows, unfortunately.)

But if the `.bin` file names always stay the same, you can create symlinks to the files directly:

```
mkdir c:\bins
mklink /f c:\bins\001.bin d:\001.bin
mklink /f c:\bins\002.bin d:\002.bin
mklink /f c:\bins\003.bin h:\003.bin
mklink /f c:\bins\004.bin h:\004.bin
...and so on
```

This could be rewritten as:

```
for /f %f in (d:\*.bin) do mklink /f "c:\bins\%~nxf" "%~f"
for /f %f in (h:\*.bin) do mklink /f "c:\bins\%~nxf" "%~f"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you will be able to get the files from `D:` and `H:` to appear as siblings within `C:\bins`. You should be able to use the following commands to build two directory junctions below `C:\bins`.

```
>mklink /D /J "C:\bins\d" "D:\"
>mklink /D /J "C:\bins\h" "H:\"
```

This will give you `c:\bins\d` and `c:\bins\h` where you will find `001.bin`,`002.bin` in `c:\bins\d` and `003.bin`, `004.bin` in `c:\bins\h`.